# Can Assistive Touch enter Command key or similar on iPhone?

Tags: ios, accessibility

Can Assistive Touch be used to enter missing keyboard keys like <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>, as if they came from a Bluetooth keyboard?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been through all the Assistive Touch settings and there is nothing for keyboard keys like <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>, <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd>, or <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>.

I also searched online and found this Apple Support Document:  [Use AssistiveTouch on your iPhone, iPad, or iPod touch](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202658)

> You can use AssistiveTouch to adjust volume, lock your screen, use multi-finger gestures, restart your device, or replace pressing buttons with just a tap.

I can summarize it like this in my own words: it is for buttons like volume or turning things on or off but, it is not for keyboard keys. Even when using the on-screen keyboard to type this, there isn’t any <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> key like when I need to paste the link (like on a Mac). I did that with a gesture of a long hold and not the keyboard shortcut(s) of  <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you. I suppose I should like to ask a new question, a more broad one, about if there could be any conceivable way to get iOS to enter the control code for that key, under any context. Maybe via JavaScript in the browser. Or, a simple DIY Bluetooth device to enable it, since it’s available via external devices.